# Reuse NLogs FileTargets FilePathLayout functionality in a custom target

Tags: nlog

I want to create a custom FileTarget for NLog (targeting LiteDB). I can't use the existing one since it's missing some features I need and afaik it's not compatible with the latest version of LiteDB. In my custom target I would like to use the [TempDir Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/TempDir-Layout-Renderer). Since NLog already has this with the FilePathLayout class, I thought I can reuse it but sadly this is declared as internal.
Am I missing something? Is there any other way to use this?

My setup:

- NLog: 4.7.2
- NLog.Web.AspNetCore: 4.9.2
- ASP.NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing a custom NLog target, then you can do this:

```
[Target("MyFirst")] 
public sealed class MyFirstTarget: TargetWithLayout 
{ 
    public MyFirstTarget()
    {
        this.Directory = "${tempdir}";
    }
 
    public Layout Directory { get; set; }
 
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
    { 
        string logMessage = RenderLogEvent(this.Layout, logEvent);
        string directory = RenderLogEvent(this.Directory, logEvent);
 
        WriteToDirectory(directory, logMessage); 
    } 
 
    private void WriteToDirectory(string directory, string message) 
    { 
        // TODO - write me 
    } 
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

Comment: Nvm, I thought I tried something like this. Thx, this works :)